# In Javascript, why does Object.getPrototypeOf([1,2]) returns an empty list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, object, prototype

In Chrome 42.0,  I assign a value to `myArray` using `var myArray = [1,2]`,

I expect `Object.getPrototypeOf(myArray)` will be like this (screenshot from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff852808.aspx))..

[image: picture1]

However, when I evaluate the code in REPL, I only got an empty list:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: seems like all correct: `Object.getPrototypeOf` return prototype, in this case - is Array, seems right

Comment: just use the `Watch Expressions` tab, like in the screenshot

Comment: Well, `Object.getPrototypeOf(myArray) == Array.prototype` for sure, so your question doesn't really have to do with that. Try `console.log(Array.prototype)` or evaluating `Array.prototype` in the REPL and see what you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the console is trying to give you its most useful representation of what you've asked for. It sees that what you've passed it is an array (`Array.isArray(Object.getPrototypeOf([1,2]))` is `true`), so it shows it using its mechanism for showing arrays. Since the [prototype array](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object) that all arrays inherit from is empty, you just see `[]`.

It does the same sort of thing for non-array objects:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf({foo:"bar"})
=> Object {}
```

*(I'm using Chrome.)*

Consoles do a fair bit of interpretation on what you pass them. Some of that interpretation isn't always useful. Example:

```
var a = [];
=> undefined
a.foo = "bar";
=> "bar"
a
=> []
```

Whereas `console.log(a)` shows the more useful

```
[foo:"bar"]
```

E.g., an array with a non-element property, `foo`, with the value `"bar"`.

Comment: Don't understand this "Since the prototype array is empty" why is it empty?

Comment: @isimmons - That's just [how it's defined](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object), the prototype used by all arrays is empty. It also makes sense. It would be weird if arrays had elements in them by default (because they inherited them from the prototype). I've reworded that sentence somewhat to hopefully make it clearer.